# Convert series from pandas DataFrame to string

Tags: python, pandas

For my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
cat: ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
step: [1,3,2, 2,1,3],
Id: [101,103,102, 902,901,903] })
```

I need to get ID values as string on output using STEP values as ordering clause:

```
cat_a: '101,102,103'
cat_b: '901,902,903'
```

I try this with heavy construction. Is there any elegant solution instead?

```
dfa = df.loc[df['cat'] == 'a', ['step', 'id']] 
dfa.set_index('step') 
a1=dfa[dfa.index == 1].iloc[0][0]
a2=dfa[dfa.index == 2].iloc[0][0]
a3=dfa[dfa.index == 3].iloc[0][0]
cat_a = '{}, {}, {}'.format(a1,a2,a3)
… 
cat_b = '{}, {}, {}'.format(b1,b2,b3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns first for expected order and then aggregate `join` with lambda method with convert to `string`s:

```
d = (df.sort_values(['cat','step'])
      .groupby('cat')['Id']
      .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
      .to_dict())
print (d)
{'a': '101,102,103', 'b': '901,902,903'}
```